# SQL oracle sum after each period

Tags: sql, oracle

I have at set of data, where I want to sum after each period. For example:

```
Period  Vessel_name Total_amount   
1301    Vessel_a    1000.00  
1301    Vessel_b    4000.00  
1302    Vessel_c    3000.00  
1302    Vessel_d    5000.00  
1302    Vessel_e    2000.00
```

I want this result:

```
Period  Vessel_name Total_amount   
1301    Vessel_a    1000.00  
1301    Vessel_b    4000.00  
Total   period      5000.00 

1302    Vessel_c    3000.00  
1302    Vessel_d    5000.00  
1302    Vessel_e    2000.00  
Total   Period      10,000,00
```

Is that possible?

I want to do this because I have a lot of data, which I update each month and therefor I don't want to make these sum each time I update the data - it is not a possibility to me to have each month in different sheets!  (dictated from the management)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use rollup to get sub sums. Use a case statement to get descriptive texts for the sub sums. Use having to get rid of the overall total.

```
select 
  case when Vessel_name is null then 'Total' else to_char(Period) end as period,
  case when Vessel_name is null then 'period' else Vessel_name end as vessel_name
  , sum(Total_amount)
from the_table
group by rollup(Period, Vessel_name)
having Period is not null;
```

Comment: The `having` is perfectly unnecessary if you [change the `group by` to `group by Period, rollup(Vessel_Name)`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3df41/2).

Answer (score 0):

U should use `rollup`.

Try this:

```
select period, vessel_name, sum(total_amount) from table group by rollup(period, vessel_name)
```

Comment: total_amount must not be in group by clause. I edited your answer accoringly.